# MySQL Recycle Table - doing replace instead of insert automatically

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table that has a lot inserts going into it.
After I get to let's say, 1,000,000 rows, I don't care anymore about the first rows, and want to delete them. 
Unfortunately, because of the high rate of inserts delete is taking too long.

To solve this I wanted to know if the following is possible - pseudo code:

```
on insert:
    if id % 1,000,000 != id:
        do replace instead of insert with id = (id % 1,000,000)
```

In this way the table would sort of "cycle" back from the top, and delete would not be necessary.

Any solution has to take into account the possibility of concurrent inserts.

Is such a thing possible?

EDIT:

For all future suggestions of delete methods - I have already tried using all the advises from http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is possible, but re-using id values is not a good practice in general.

What I would recommend is that you delete rows in smaller batches.

Suppose you want to delete all rows with id < 800,000

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id < 800000 LIMIT 1000;
```

Then do that in a loop, until the *rows affected* is 0.

You can also add a brief sleep in your loop, to allow the deletes to happen gradually over time, without putting too much load on your database server.

You might also like to try out [pt-archiver](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-archiver.html) in the free Percona Toolkit This is a script designed to do exactly this sort of gradual pruning.

```
pt-archiver --purge --where "id < 800000" --source h=myserver,D=mydatabase,t=mytable
```

Comment: I completely understand this might not be a good practice, but as I mentioned in my question delete is not fast enough to keep up, no matter what batch size I choose. 
Please look at my edit for more information.

Comment: Then you either need a faster server, or else multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITIONing` would be the optimal way to "delete old" stuff.  I explain the details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint  But, initially setting it up will take some downtime.  The benefit is that periodic `DELETEs` are replaced by near-instantaneous `DROP PARTITION`.

It is possible to `DELETE` in chunks with minimal impact on the system.  I discuss chunking here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Or...

You can simply do `REPLACE` always.  `REPLACE` is two steps:  `DELETE` any row(s) that match on `UNIQUE` (incl. `PRIMARY`) key, then `INSERT`.

Comment: I did end up using partitioning, though I was still hoping to get an answer to my question, which is not how to delete, but whether the suggested scheme is possible, and if so how.